# iphone dev - how to catch exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

In my app I try to scroll a UITableView to the top once after I updated the content of the table. However, under some circumstance, my table is EMPTY. So I got the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

how can I catch this exception? I tried

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

if (indexPath != nil) {
    [EventTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

but it doesn't catch the exception because indexPath is not nil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before scrolling to an IndexPath, check your UITableView to make sure the row and section you're trying to scroll to are less than the number of rows and section in your table, respectively. If so, do not try to scroll to that IndexPath.

```
if ( [tableView numberOfSections] < section || [tableView numberOfRowsInSection] < row )
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I do it.
if (([EventTable numberOfSections] > 0) && ([EventTable numberOfRowsInSection: 0] > 0)) {
  [EventTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
 }

Comment: @S.P that depends if you're testing whether to scroll, or testing whether to abort.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ([tableView numberOfSections] - 1 < artistsSection  || [tableView numberOfRowsInSection: artistsSection] - 1 < artistsRow)` so we consider the index starts with 0?

Answer (score 6):

Exception handling takes a different path than your typical flow control expressions. Apple has written up a useful article on [Objective-C Exception Handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH13-SW1). Essentially you'll want to wrap your code in `@try`/`@catch` blocks. It is in the `@catch` block where you will receive the exception and perform the appropriate next steps in your code.

Comment: @try/@catch works but I always try to avoid using it. I think it is better to avoid the exception than catch it when it happens =) but thanks

Comment: Agreed- your question was asking specifically for how to catch the exception, not how to avoid it; I was trying to answer that for you.

Comment: Article link has changed: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH13-SW1

Comment: The article link has changed again: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html